# Let $H$ a subgroup of $G$. $\exists g \in G$, $g \notin H$, such that $gH=Hg$, and $[G:H]$ is a prime p. Prove that $H$ is normal.

Tags: group-theory

Past year exam question:

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Suppose there exist some $g \in G$, $g \notin H$, such that $gH=Hg$, and $[G:H]$ is a prime p. Prove that $H$ is normal.

Sketch:
We have $H, gH, g^2H, ... g^{p-1}H$ to be the cosets of $H$. Then for any $x \in G$, $x=g^kh$ for some $h \in H$ and $k$ integer. Then $x^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-k}$.

Then $xHx^{-1} = g^khHh^{-1}g^{-k} = ... = H$. Hence $H$ is normal in $G$.

I am not sure about my proof, because I don't know how to show that $g^kH$ can generate all the cosets.

Is there a way to show that this is the case? Or if not, how to go about proving this question?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: Consider the normalizer $N_G(H)$ and note that $g\in N_G(H)$. What can the index of this be in $G$ then?

Comment: @eatfood : "I am not sure about my proof, because I don't know how to show that gkH can generate all the cosets." What can you say about $g^kH\cap g^mH$ for $k,m\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071049/gh-3-and-exists-x-in-g-setminus-h-such-that-xh-hx-prove-h-is-no?rq=1), for $p=3$, but it works in general.

Comment: @YadatiKiran They are disjoint? But I don't see how that shows the $g^kH$ can generate all the cosets. What if it can only generate like half the cosets

Comment: @DietrichBurde That is a nice proof. If H has index 5 for e.g., then the cosets could be $\{ H, gH, xH, yH, zH \}$ and the right cosets could be $\{ H, Hg, Hx, Hy, Hz \}$ but in this case we can't say that $xH=Hx$, $yH=Hy$ etc?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I was hoping for an elementary solution for this one haha.

Comment: @eatfood: Any two cosets of $H$ in $G$ are either identical or have no element in common. $[G:H]$ gives a partition of $G$ into cosets $g^kH$ such that each coset has exactly $o(H)$ number of elements.

Comment: Indeed the cosets cosets $g^kH$ exhaust $G$. If not the index will not be an integer.

Comment: ok i see it now. if $gH=Hg$, then $g^2H=Hg^2$ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very straighforward proof can be obtained by remarking the following:

1. If $K \leqslant G$ is a subgroup such that the index $(G \colon K)=p$ is prime, then $K$ is a *maximal* subgroup of $G$. Indeed, given the situation $K \leqslant E \leqslant G$, we have $(G\colon K)=(G \colon E)(E \colon K)$, which means that $(E\colon K)$ and $(G\colon E)$ are both natural and furthermore divide $p$. Therefore, we either have $(E \colon K)=1$ in which case $E=K$ or $(E\colon K)=p$ in which case we derive $(G \colon E)=1$ and hence $G=E$.
2. In the particular case of your problem, the normaliser $H <\mathrm{N}_G(H)$ contains an element in $G \setminus H$ by hypothesis and is thus compelled to be the improper subgroup -- in other words $\mathrm{N}_G(H)=G$ -- by the above observation. This means that $H \trianglelefteq G$ is normal.

Comment: Thank you for making this answer. Did you mean $N_G(H) = G$ rather than $N_G(H) = H$?

Comment: @eatfood Yes indeed, it is the price to pay for committing to such proof-writing tasks at late hours of the night....